# Recorrey array dentro de array JSON

Tags: php, laravel, json, array, foreach

Necesito reccorer el array de 'productos'  dentro de este json

Intente con este foreach, pero me retorna 'Array to string conversion'

```
@foreach ($datos['productos'] as $clave => $valor)
  {{ $clave . ' => ' . $valor}}
@endforeach
```

Este es mi JSON

```
{
"estatus": "correcto",
"mensaje": "transaccion correcta, CVECHES",
"productos": [{
        "transactionid": 1754030,
        "nombre": "Peluche Perro comiendo pollo 20cm",
        "precio": 122,
        "estatus": "activo",
        "ean": "",
        "claroid": null,
        "skupadre": "PELU54",
        "fulfillment": false
    },
    {
        "transactionid": 1754002,
        "nombre": "Peluche Perro cafÃ© oscuro acostado 60 cm",
        "precio": 421,
        "estatus": "activo",
        "ean": "",
        "claroid": null,
        "skupadre": "PELU15",
        "fulfillment": false
    },
],
"totalproductos": 1662,
"totalpaginas": 56,
"paginaactual": 1,
"productosporpagina": 30
}
```

Intente con un dobles foearch, recorriendo datos y luego datos->productos pero sigue sin funcionar

Comment: En algún momento transformás el JSON en un array? Por ejemplo con `json_decode($datos)`. De dónde sale ese JSON? Asumo que estás trabajando con Laravel y eso es Blade, correcto?

Comment: Esos son registros de una api, y si estan tranformados a json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ví que en el json de ejemplo hay un error de sintaxis, en el array de productos tienes una coma de mas al final del segundo producto.

Añado ejemplo donde estaba el error:

```
{
    "estatus": "correcto",
    "mensaje": "transaccion correcta, CVECHES",
    "productos": [
            {
                    "transactionid": 1754030,
                    "nombre": "Peluche Perro comiendo pollo 20cm",
                    "precio": 122,
                    "estatus": "activo",
                    "ean": "",
                    "claroid": null,
                    "skupadre": "PELU54",
                    "fulfillment": false
            },
            {
                    "transactionid": 1754002,
                    "nombre": "Peluche Perro cafÃ© oscuro acostado 60 cm",
                    "precio": 421,
                    "estatus": "activo",
                    "ean": "",
                    "claroid": null,
                    "skupadre": "PELU15",
                    "fulfillment": false
            }, // Esta coma es el error de sintaxis
    ],
    "totalproductos": 1662,
    "totalpaginas": 56,
    "paginaactual": 1,
    "productosporpagina": 30
    }
```

Añado un ejemplo en php mostrando nombres de productos:

```
<?php

$json = '{
    "estatus": "correcto",
    "mensaje": "transaccion correcta, CVECHES",
    "productos": [
            {
                    "transactionid": 1754030,
                    "nombre": "Peluche Perro comiendo pollo 20cm",
                    "precio": 122,
                    "estatus": "activo",
                    "ean": "",
                    "claroid": null,
                    "skupadre": "PELU54",
                    "fulfillment": false
            },
            {
                    "transactionid": 1754002,
                    "nombre": "Peluche Perro cafÃ© oscuro acostado 60 cm",
                    "precio": 421,
                    "estatus": "activo",
                    "ean": "",
                    "claroid": null,
                    "skupadre": "PELU15",
                    "fulfillment": false
            }
    ],
    "totalproductos": 1662,
    "totalpaginas": 56,
    "paginaactual": 1,
    "productosporpagina": 30
    }';

$objeto = json_decode($json);

foreach ($objeto->productos as $producto) {
    echo $producto->nombre;
}
```

Espero haber ayudado, un saludo.

Comment: Excelente, muchas gracias :D, me sirvió muchísimo